# How to show file upload progress for each file with AWS Javascript SDK?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-javascript-sdk

I am trying to upload file to AWS S3 and its working fine. But when the file upload is going on for multiple files , how do i get the progress for each file. Below is my code in AngularJs

```
upload: function (file) {
    options = {
        accessKeyId : 'xxxxxxx',
        secretAccessKey : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        region : 'xxxxxx'
    }

    var s3 = new AWS.S3(options);

    var params = {
        Bucket : bucketStructure,
        Key: file.name,
        ContentType: file.type,
        Body: file,
        ServerSideEncryption: 'xxxx',
        ACL : 'private'
    };

    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        // There Was An Error With Your S3 Config
        alert('AWS Error : '+err.message);
        return false;
      }
      else {
        // Success!
        alert('Upload Done');
      }
    })
    .on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {                        
        //console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100) + '% done');
    });

}
```

I am calling the above code which is in a service function, in a loop. So when the user clicks on form submit button, i get the two files to upload and in a loop below i am calling the above function:

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.awsfiles, function (file) {
                        FileFactory.Upload(file);
                    });
```

Now how do i get to know for which file the progress to show ?? Any other better ideas to get this working?? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you would need to use multipart upload, and for that direct access to the file, what would require either a recent browser with the File API or a extension (Java/Flash).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Julio. Could you please provide some pointers or a code example?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS but never tried.